# UPSmart always gives "connection failure" when connecting to UPS through USB

Tags: ubuntu, usb, ups

I want to connect UPS (Irbis ISL1000ET) to OS (Ubuntu 18.04), so that when power is off and battery is low, OS shuts down automatically.

However I cannot do this -  I installed with superuser UPSmart program (officially distributed with the UPS) to the default location (/opt/UPSmart), ran it with superuser, but it cannot connect to UPS through USB - neither "Single phase UPS (USB)", nor "Three phase UPS (USB)", nor "Mega (USB)" modes connect.

Should I install any additional drivers or use other software to let the UPS shut down my computer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work on UBUNTU a udev rule was needed as per the below:

---

```
# This is a sample udev file for HIDAPI devices which changes the permissions
# to 0666 (world readable/writable) for a specified device on Linux systems.


# If you are using the libusb implementation of hidapi (libusb/hid.c), then
# use something like the following line, substituting the VID and PID with
# those of your device. Note that for kernels before 2.6.24, you will need
# to substitute "usb" with "usb_device". It shouldn't hurt to use two lines
# (one each way) for compatibility with older systems.

# HIDAPI/libusb
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0001", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", MODE="0666"


# If you are using the hidraw implementation (linux/hid.c), then do something
# like the following, substituting the VID and PID with your device. Busnum 1
# is USB.

# HIDAPI/hidraw
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{busnum}=="1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0001", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", MODE="0666"

# Once done, optionally rename this file for your device, and drop it into
# /etc/udev/rules.d and unplug and re-plug your device. This is all that is
# necessary to see the new permissions. Udev does not have to be restarted.

# Note that the hexadecimal values for VID and PID are case sensitive and
# must be lower case.

# If you think permissions of 0666 are too loose, then see:
# http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html for more information on finer
# grained permission setting. For example, it might be sufficient to just
# set the group or user owner for specific devices (for example the plugdev
# group on some systems).
```